# The name does not exist in the current context - Methodes

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to have a more clean code, so I tried packing my code in a method.
This is how I tried

I have a method:

```
endScreen();
```

Followed by:

```
private static void endScreen()
    {
        //Game Over
        isGameOn = false;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(25, 12);
        Console.WriteLine("Game Over!");

        //Show Score  
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(27, 14);
        Console.Write("Your Score is: " + itemEaten * 100 + "!");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(26, 13);
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter To Continue.");
        itemEaten = 0;
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Clear();
    }
```

The error i get is:

> Error CS0103  The name **'isGameOn'** does not exist in the current
>
> Error   CS0103  The name **'itemEaten'** does not exist in the current context

Comment: variables `isGameOn` and `itemEaten` are not defined. That's what is the error. You need to define those variables.

Comment: Are you sure you want the function to be `static`?

Comment: _"so i tried packing my code in a method"_ If you had `isGameOn` and `itemEaten` as local variables in the previous code, you should either declare them globally, locally inside the method, or pass them as parameters. Of course, that depends on what you're planning to use them for.

Comment: From where you are calling the method `endScreen()` and where the variable `isGameOn` is defined

Comment: Where's your declaration for `isGameOn` and `itemEaten`???

Answer (score 0):

Add `var` keyword before the variables.

```
var isGameOn = false;
var itemEaten = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use var keyword or if you know the data types use those.

```
bool isGameOn = false;
int itemEaten = 0;
```